# Configuring XPath and use LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

i have a scenario where i need to check for the node count in a XML file. Since the XPath may vary for different scenarios, i would like to configure this in a xml / text file

I checked at XQuery but I hardly find any implementation in C#.

Since LINQ also does the similar thing, i am thinking of using it.

Ex. XML:

```
<ROOT><NODE1><TXT>ABC</TXT></NODE1><NODE1><TXT>DEF</TXT></NODE1></ROOT>
```

I would like to configure my condition like this (in a text file):

```
/ROOT/NODE1/TXT [COUNT=2]
```

there will n-number of xpath like this

How easily can I use LINQ, Check for XPATH and get the count?

Thanks in advance

Cheers,
Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
int count = doc.Descendants("TXT").Count();
```

In this case you can do:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
        var xPath = @"/ROOT/NODE1/TXT";
        int count = doc.Descendants(xPath.Substring(xPath.LastIndexOf("//") + 1)).Count();
```

but it's not general case, whould you explain more details about your condition to force using XPath strings?

Comment: Thanks. Instead of ("TXT") can will I be able to provide the XPAHT which i have configured? I dont want to hardcode any XPATH in my code.

Comment: Great. Let me try this. Thanks for fast response

Comment: I used doc.XPathSelectElements(xpath) and this worked. Just incase if some one is also trying the same.  Additional info: http://www.microsoft.com/uk/msdn/nuggets/nugget/288/LINQ-to-XML-Querying-with-XPath.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Check the reference `System.Xml.Xpath` which allows you to use xpath to work with Xml data.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
var xPath = @"/ROOT/NODE1/TXT";
int count = doc.XPathSelectElements(xPath).Count();
```